# GEE: mask MODIS with CDL then count CDL pixel number in one MODIS pixel

Tags: google-earth-engine

This code is to get an image from MODIS dataset, select one area planted with corn by CDL mask('cropland' band), calculate the EVI of each pixel, and randomly sample 500 pixels to CSV file. you can run the code in:

https://code.earthengine.google.com/9ba4ad6dac0d0563875d81302e979d79

```
// Function to transform weather collection to an image
function appendBand(current, previous){
  // Append it to the result (only return current item on first element)
  var accum = ee.Algorithms.If(ee.Algorithms.IsEqual(previous,null), current, ee.Image(previous).addBands(ee.Image(current)));
  // return the accumulation
  return accum;
};

var addEVI = function(image) {
  var evi = image.expression(
      '2.5 * (nir - red) / (nir + 6 * red - 7.5 * blue + 10000)',
        {
          red: image.select([0]).float(),    // 620-670nm, RED
          nir: image.select([1]).float(),    // 841-876nm, NIR
          blue: image.select([2]).float()   // 459-479nm, BLUE
        });
  
  return image.addBands(evi.updateMask(evi.gt(0)).updateMask(evi.lt(1)).unmask().rename('EVI'))
};


var exportData = function(table, prefix) {
  Export.table.toDrive({
    collection: table,
    description: prefix,
    folder: 'test',  //*********
    fileNamePrefix: prefix
  });
};


var rectangle = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([
    -88, 36, -91, 38
]);

var trueColorViz = {
  bands: ['EVI'],
  min: 0,
  max: 1,
  gamma: 1.3
};

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('USDA/NASS/CDL')
  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2020-01-01', '2020-12-31'))
  .first()
  
var cropMask = dataset.select('cropland').eq(1); //1 - corn, 5 -soybeans
print('cropMask', cropMask)
Map.addLayer(cropMask, {palette: ['blue', 'lightgreen']}, 'cropMask');

var modVI = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MCD43A4')
              .filterDate('2020-03-01','2020-10-31')
              .filterBounds(rectangle)
              .map(function(img){return img.updateMask(cropMask)})
              .map(addEVI)
              .select(['EVI'])
print('modVI', modVI)

var modVIStack = ee.Image(modVI.iterate(appendBand));
print('modVIStack', modVIStack)
Map.addLayer(modVIStack, trueColorViz, 'modVIStack');


var f = modVIStack.sample({
  region: rectangle, 
  scale: 30, 
  projection: 'EPSG:4326', 
  numPixels: 500, 
  tileScale: 8,
  geometries: true});
  
exportData(f, 'Data_2020_STATE_17_COUNTY_0');
```

The resulting CSV file will be like this:

[image]

where each row represents a masked MODIS pixel, which has the property "EVI" and ".geo".

We know the CDL resolution is 30m, and the MODIS resolution is 500m, when I use CDL to mask MODIS, every MODIS pixel containing CDL pixel labeled "1" will be selected, like this:

[image]

So now I want to calculate, how many CDL pixels labeled "1" are there in one MODIS pixel, and export the number to CSV, like this:

[image]

where each MODIS pixel has one property "number", which indicates how many CDL pixels are in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach involves several steps.

1. Producing a grid with 'coveringGrid' method for each involved image (**modVIStack** and **cropMask**) by using as reference **rectangle** area.
2. Mapping **Feature Collection** named f (sampled points) for extracting, from **grid_pol_modis**, the geometries (**modisPixels** layer) associated to each point in f.
3. Clipping **cropMask** image with **modisPixels** layer for obtaining an image with 500 modis pixels areas.
4. Using 'reduceRegions' method, with **ee.Reducer.frequencyHistogram** (scale 30 of **cropMask** image), to count CDL pixels labeled 0 and 1.
5. Selecting CDL pixels labeled with 1 for setting them as property (number) in f Feature Collection.
6. Exporting **Data_2020_STATE_17_COUNTY_0** file to Drive.

Complete code can be found [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/6afbe1652ad1f2de2fd7812c52a92987) and as follows:

```
Map.setOptions('SATELLITE');

// Function to transform weather collection to an image
function appendBand(current, previous){
  // Append it to the result (only return current item on first element)
  var accum = ee.Algorithms.If(ee.Algorithms.IsEqual(previous,null), current, ee.Image(previous).addBands(ee.Image(current)));
  // return the accumulation
  return accum;
}

var addEVI = function(image) {
  var evi = image.expression(
      '2.5 * (nir - red) / (nir + 6 * red - 7.5 * blue + 10000)',
        {
          red: image.select([0]).float(),    // 620-670nm, RED
          nir: image.select([1]).float(),    // 841-876nm, NIR
          blue: image.select([2]).float()   // 459-479nm, BLUE
        });
  
  return image.addBands(evi.updateMask(evi.gt(0)).updateMask(evi.lt(1)).unmask().rename('EVI'));
};

var exportData = function(table, prefix) {
  Export.table.toDrive({
    collection: table,
    description: prefix,
    folder: 'test',  //*********
    fileNamePrefix: prefix
  });
};

var rectangle = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([
    -88, 36, -91, 38
]);

rectangle = rectangle.buffer(200);

var trueColorViz = {
  bands: ['EVI'],
  min: 0,
  max: 1,
  gamma: 1.3
};

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('USDA/NASS/CDL')
  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2020-01-01', '2020-12-31'))
  .first();
  
var cropMask = dataset.select('cropland').eq(1); //1 - corn, 5 -soybeans
print('cropMask', cropMask);

cropMask = cropMask.clip(rectangle);

Map.addLayer(cropMask, {palette: ['blue', 'lightgreen']}, 'cropMask', false);

var modVI = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MCD43A4')
              .filterDate('2020-03-01','2020-10-31')
              .filterBounds(rectangle)
              .map(function(img){return img.updateMask(cropMask)})
              .map(addEVI)
              .select(['EVI']);
              
print('modVI', modVI);

var modVIStack = ee.Image(modVI.iterate(appendBand));
print('modVIStack', modVIStack);

modVIStack = modVIStack.clip(rectangle);

var imageVisParam = {"opacity":1,
                     "bands":["EVI"],
                     "max":0.32794995935964943,
                     "palette":["ff1b02","ff9d06","ffed04","41ff04","17ae05"]};

//Map.addLayer(modVIStack, imageVisParam, 'modVIStack');
//Map.addLayer(rectangle);

var proj_modis = modVIStack.select('EVI').projection();
var proj_cropmask =cropMask.projection();

//print('scale_modis', proj_modis.nominalScale());
//print('scale_cropmask', proj_cropmask.nominalScale());

var f = modVIStack.sample({
  region: rectangle, 
  scale: 30, 
  projection: 'EPSG:4326', 
  numPixels: 500, 
  tileScale: 8,
  geometries: true});

var grid_pol_modis = rectangle.coveringGrid(proj_modis);
var grid_pol_cropmask = rectangle.coveringGrid(proj_cropmask);

// add to map
//Map.addLayer(grid_pol_modis, {}, 'grid modis', true, 0.5);
Map.addLayer(grid_pol_cropmask, {}, 'grid cropmask', true, 0.5);

var modisPixels = f.map(function (ele) {
  
  return ee.FeatureCollection(grid_pol_modis.filterBounds(ee.Feature(ele).geometry()))                                                                .first();
  
});

print("modisPixels", modisPixels);

Map.addLayer(modisPixels, {}, 'modisPixels', true, 0.5);

var image = cropMask.clip(modisPixels);

var imageVisParam = {"opacity":1,
                     "bands":["cropland"],
                     "palette":["blue","lightgreen"]};

Map.addLayer(image, imageVisParam, 'image');

var countByCropMask = image.reduceRegions(modisPixels, ee.Reducer.frequencyHistogram(), 30);

print("countByCropMask", countByCropMask);

Map.addLayer(f, {}, 'points');

//var pt = ee.Geometry.Point(-89.84259560627622,36.967613591583);
var pt = ee.Geometry.Point(-88.30163937451594,37.39540540736847);

Map.centerObject(pt, 16);

var list = countByCropMask.toList(countByCropMask.size());

var count = list.map(function (ele) {
  
  var keys = ee.List(ee.Dictionary(ee.Feature(ele).get('histogram')).keys());
  var size = keys.size();
  
  var values = ee.List(ee.Dictionary(ee.Feature(ele).get('histogram')).values());
  
  var opt = ee.Algorithms.If(size.eq(1), [values.get(0), 0], [values.get(0), values.get(1)]);
  
  return ee.Number(ee.List(opt).get(1)).format('%.0f');
  
});

print("count", count);

var f_list = f.toList(f.size());

f = f.map(function (feat) {
  
  var idx = ee.List(f_list).indexOf(feat);
  
  return feat.set('number', ee.List(count).get(idx));
  
});

print("points", f);

exportData(f, 'Data_2020_STATE_17_COUNTY_0');
```

After running it at GEE code editor, I got following result for selected point in -88.301639,37.395405 (feature 209). The count for CDL pixels labeled with 1, inside Modis pixel, was 203 (count for CDL pixels labeled with 0 was 35). I tested several points and the results were as expected.

[image]

An extract of exported file **Data_2020_STATE_17_COUNTY_0** it can be observed at following picture; where it can also be corroborated the data corresponding to feature with id equals 209.

[image]

**Editing Note:**

Above code was developed for testing my approach. However, the count changes when both images have the same projection. So, including it as follows:

```
modVIStack = modVIStack.reproject('EPSG:5070', null, proj_modis.nominalScale());
var proj_modis = modVIStack.select('EVI').projection();
```

result with the [new code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/e828282b600d64da828f1a934ba283e9) looks as follows:

[image]

where the counts for each modis pixels, at exported file to Google Drive, are markedly different.

Comment: thank you! your answer is very accurate and reliable, and I post an approximate answer below. Could you please help me check if the general idea is correct?

Comment: You're welcome. Can you supply a link with the complete code for your approximate answer? It will be easier for me to check it.

Comment: https://code.earthengine.google.com/d8f046e2c734f5352e1b75c682284528

it's just an approximate result, but I think it's easier and enough for my need

Comment: No, it's not just an approximate result. Your approach is not good. Your results are very different from mine (by the way, I modified my code to consider **proportion** variable instead number).

Comment: thanks! I'd better use your method

Comment: Yes, it would be better. I tested with other points with almost 100 % of crop covering (proportion about 0.9) and it looks perfect,